# How to generate the same tokens?

Tags: session, token

Is there any way to generate these kinda tokens?

https://xxxxx.xxxx.net/master.m3u8?token=oP3fVd6FFij37EGXOUVeyQ&expires=1611934289
https://xxx.xxx.net/master.m3u8?token=D08YUMgLwTGq4DZ6_fzUag&expires=1611934522
https://xxx.xxx.net/master.m3u8?token=08zGTcJWzN9qBlVlduig6g&expires=1611934559